# Internationalization and localization Testing: How to test app on Android which do not have that particular language support

Tags: manual-testing, mobile, android, languages

I feel like I'm chasing my tail on this one, but I need to be able to test in languages not listed under Settings > Language & Input > Language. I've spoken with Samsung & Motorola and they tell me that it is impossible. I'm not willing to accept that answer as I know there has to be a way to test language support for the mobile apps I test. This is where Android gets stingy and makes Apple look like the savior of all things.

Comment: I am not sure if you can test a language which is not supported by itself.

Comment: Brenda, If any answer helps you pls accept. So this Q will not be in active state for long

Comment: What language do you need? If you can indicate one it may help attracting a useful answer.

Comment: Anyway this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32035573/change-language-in-android-app-to-unsupported-language

Answer (score 0):

That particular phone doesn't support that languages you want? Hacking your code or hacking you device undermine your attempts to simulate a realistic situation. Perhaps you can install a vanilla android OS on the phone that does have these languages.

Otherwise, buy another phone or use an emulator, either for free on your pc, or maybe even use an emulation service like browserstack. If it can't be done on the free emulator, yet there isnt budget for the other two options, the test probably isn't worth doing.

Answer (score -1):

@Brenda - Its **really not convincing saying I'm not willing to accept answer from Samsung & Moto**.

- Could we use any hardware with our computer, without using its drivers? [software required to interact with hardware]

Everyone knows answer, Right!

Its similar to your scenario, when **device is not supporting any particular language** that simply means that the device is not having instructions about "**How to deal with it & How to display the text**" in particular language.

**We can not by pass this! We can test app with only those languages which your device supports.**

Comment: I'm confused - so you're saying it is logically impossible? That there is no way to, say, hack in additional languages somehow? Or are you saying that the question has a faulty premise?

Comment: @corsika, Question may arise,thats fine. But it's not possible with even hack.

Comment: If you're saying it's not possible, then the burden would be on you to prove it is not possible. Otherwise, we should leave it open for someone to come up with some (very creative) way to do it. It may be the question is open and unanswered forever. But if we can't prove it's impossible, then we shouldn't say it is.

Comment: I've used third party drivers before, but I get that this is an analogue, what's your actually point?